# ejecutar una funcion con parametro

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una etiqueta con la llamada

```
onclick="cargarusuario(22)"
```

y una funcion para que se ejecute que es:

```
function cargarusuario(petid){
var petides=petid;
console.log(petides);
}
```

eso funciona correctamente, pero si en el onclick le paso el parametro "a" ya no me funciona

```
onclick="cargarusuario(a)"
```

me salta un error...

como puedo ponerle en el onclick un string (tiene que llevar simbolos como el "-" y el "==") si es posible

Comment: Intenta con onclick="cargarusuario('a')", saludos.

Comment: como tengo que crear la etiqueta desde JS tengo que añadirle &apos; sino no sirve, graicas!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la funciones de javascript si quieres pasar un caracter o un string tienes que ponerle comillas simples,

```
onclick="cargarusuario('a')"
```

Si no no lo sabe interpretar, en cambio si es numerico no hace falta o si es un true o false tampoco.

Answer (score 0):

Mi consejo es que no uses los atributos HTML para añadir listeners. Añade los eventos desde el propio Javascript, usando algo como

```javascript
let boton = document.getElementById('boton-carga');
boton.addEventListener('click',() => cargarusuario('a');
```

Comment: no puedo hacerlo así, es que cargo desde un api una serie de usuarios cada uno con un id, así que cuando los listo, pongo que al pulsar sobre ellos cargue la funcion con su id personal y así acceder desde otro api a sus datos

Comment: Si añades dinámicamente la lista, de igual modo se puede hacer con los event listeners.